# adding contrast to an image in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, contrast

I am trying to work through a process where I take an astronomical fits file, subtract a masterflat file and then later the contrast on the resultant image.

The first part has been done successfully but my image lacks contrast. Here's my code

```
   from astropy.io.fits import getdata
   import numpy
   import numpy as np
   import scipy
   import Image 
   import PIL
   import os
   os.chdir("/localdir/")
   from scipy import misc
   import ImageEnhance


   image = getdata('23484748.fts')
   flat = getdata('Masterflat.fit')

   normalized_flat = flat / numpy.mean(flat)
   calibrated_image = image / normalized_flat
   pix=numpy.fliplr(calibrated_image)

   # the problem starts about here. How do I alter the contrast of pix?


   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   misc.imsave('saved image.gif', pix) # uses the Image module (PIL)
   plt.imshow(pix, interpolation='nearest')
   plt.show()
```

Now before you tell me all about PIL functions and Matlib etc I have tried these without success.

I have tried to use image.fromarray to convert my numpy array into an image but the resultant image displays as pure white.

How can I take my numpy array (pix) and change its contrast?

For testing purposes I have put the two sample files at http://members.optusnet.com.au/berrettp/

Thanking you

Peter

Comment: Almost 6 years without an answer....